How to Create valuechange detection of the formcontrol which is inside the form array of the another form group in angular 18
I have a form with a FormArray that dynamically adds rows with multiple fields, including unit, quantity, and remarks. Here’s a snippet of my template where I loop through the unitDetails FormArray:
<tbody formArrayName="unitDetails">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of unitDetails.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="unit" placeholder="Enter Name" /></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" /></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="remarks" placeholder="Enter Remarks" /></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUnitRow(i)">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

The form is structured like this:
this.form = this.fb.group({
  unitDetails: this.fb.array([]), // Group for Unit, Quantity, Remarks
  discountDetails: this.fb.array([]), // Group for Qty From, Qty To, Discount, Cash Discount
  statusGroup: this.fb.group({
    status: ['']
  })
});

I want to add a valueChanges handler for the quantity form control inside the unitDetails FormArray to ensure that only numeric values are allowed. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
form.get('quantity')?.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
  console.log(values);
});

However, this doesn't work because quantity is inside a FormArray, and I'm unable to access it directly.
How can I track changes for the quantity field within the FormArray and modify the value to accept only numbers? I would also like to prevent non-numeric input.
Can anyone provide a solution or guide me on how to achieve this in Angular?

If you want only numeric values, then you should set it as type="number".
<td><input class="form-control" type="number" formControlName="unit" placeholder="Enter Name" /></td>

To save you some complicated code, I suggested this simple method of using the (input) event which will fire the same as valueChange and you can use this with less amount of code.
<tbody formArrayName="unitDetails">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of unitDetails.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="unit" placeholder="Enter Name" (input)="unitChange($event)"/></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" (input)="quantityChange($event)"/></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" formControlName="remarks" placeholder="Enter Remarks" (input)="remarksChange($event)"/></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUnitRow(i)">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

Then you can acess the value like:
unitChange(event: any) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  console.log('unit change: ', value); 
}


If you decide use with valueChanges, you'll need to manage subscriptions for each control in the FormArray dynamically, like:
this.form.get('unitDetails')?.valueChanges.subscribe((unitDetails: formArry[]) => {
  unitDetails.forEach((unitDetail, index) => {
    const quantityControl = (this.form.get('unitDetails') as FormArray).at(index).get('quantity');
    quantityControl?.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
       console.log(value) // Now you can access the value
    });
  });
});

But for your case, my recommendation for you is create a directive, or apply a validador directly in the formControl.
Validador, can be something like that:
this.fb.group({
  unit: [''],
  quantity: ['', Validators.pattern('here you must to create a numeric pattern')], // Numeric validation
  remarks: ['']
});

You can read more here Validator Pattern doc
Or a directive:
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumericOnly]'
})
export class NumericOnlyDirective {
  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onInput(event: Event): void {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const numericValue = inputElement.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // Remove non-numeric characters
    if (inputElement.value !== numericValue) {
      inputElement.value = numericValue;
      this.ngControl.control?.setValue(numericValue); // Update the FormControl value
    }
  }
}

After create your directive you need to import it, in your component and add to the quantity field in your FormArray template;
<td><input class="form-control" appNumericOnly formControlName="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" /></td>

You also can read more in the Official Angular documentation
